# Layering a heatmap onto a map from a data array

Tags: python, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap (if possible layered on top of a map of my area of interest). I have an array of data (Sea surface temperatures) for the Mediterranean Sea and I would like to generate a heatmap (red for hotter, blue for colder regions) and if possible layer this onto a map (such as google maps or similar) in order to make my data more readable. Are there any packages that can help me with this/does anyone know where I could look to find some sample scripts? Thanks for you help!

I have tried using plotly and matplotlib, however these do not give the desired heatmap (it is all one colour).

Comment: This is called "Geographic Heat Map". There's a Python Package called Alcid – https://alcidanalytics.com/p/geographic-heatmap-in-python – that provides the desired features

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to explain my second problem. I have extracted this data from a raster image, which is 380 rows x 1020 columns of pixels big. I know the top left coordinate has a lat/long value of (-7,48). My data is now a DataFrame (i used Pandas to do this). How do I add the georeferencing into the array so that I can map this?